# Graphing code size

Tags: optimization, gcc, d3.js, size, gnuplot

I was curious if there exists a ready-made script that would provide some starting point for an ultimate code size tracker tool. To start with I'd like to be able to graph size with various optimisation options for an number of cross-compiler targets and I'm quite tempted to put this on revision timeline later as well.

So taken the output from `size` command:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1634       0     128    1762     6e2 csv_data.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
     28       0       0      28      1c csv_data_layer.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
   1063       0       0    1063     427 http_parser.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
   1312       0    1024    2336     920 http_queries.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
      8      36       0      44      2c transport.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
   1748       0    3688    5436    153c transport_layer.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
      8       0       0       8       8 misc_allocator.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
    847     108       1     956     3bc misc_err.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
      0       4       0       4       4 misc_globals.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
    273       0       0     273     111 misc_helpers.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
     71       0       4      75      4b misc_printf.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
   1044       0      44    1088     440 misc_time.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
   3724       0       0    3724     e8c xyz.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
    627       0       0     627     273 dummy.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
      8      16       0      24      18 dummy_layer.o (ex libs/libxyz.a)
  12395     164    4889   17448    4428 (TOTALS)
```

With most of values being different when the library is being compiled with various optimisation flags (i.e.: `-Os`, `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`) and a variety of cross-compilers (e.g.: AVR, MSP430, ARMv6, i386), I'd like to make a combined graph or set of graphs using either *gnuplot*, *d3.js*, *matplotlib* or any other package. Has anyone have a seen ready-made script which would help this partially (e.g. at least convert the above tabular format to CSV, JSON or XML) or some study paper that presents a decent visualisation example? I have to admit, it's rather hard to find this using a web search engine.

Comment: There's nothing "ready-made" for this with D3, but it sounds like what you want is a fairly straightforward bar chart.

Comment: Yeah, D3 would be nice... but other graphing tool would work for me fine also ;)

Comment: Have you seen [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/)? That would almost certainly be a faster way to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible visualization of the data as bar chart using `gnuplot`. This is of course not the ultimate visualization, but should be a good starting point.

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid 1.0 border lc rgb "white"
set xtics rotate 90
set key outside reverse Left
set bmargin 8
plot 'file.dat' using (!(stringcolumn(6) eq "(TOTALS)") ? column(1) : 1/0):xtic(6) title columnheader(1), \
     for [i=2:5] '' using (!(stringcolumn(6) eq "(TOTALS)") ? column(i) : 1/0) title columnheader(i)
```

With the settings `set terminal pngcairo size 1000,800`, this gives

[image]

You must also decide, which columns you want to use, because plotting *every column* for *every file* for *every compiler* will be quite messy. Maybe you want to plot only the size:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set xtics rotate 90
set key outside reverse Left
set bmargin 8
plot 'file.dat' using (!(stringcolumn(6) eq "(TOTALS)") ? $4 : 1/0):xtic(6) title 'i386', \
     '' using (!(stringcolumn(6) eq "(TOTALS)") ? $4*1.2 : 1/0) title 'ARMv6',\
     '' using (!(stringcolumn(6) eq "(TOTALS)") ? $4*0.7 : 1/0) title 'AVR'
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Note, that the lengthy `using` statements are only to skip the last line with the `TOTAL`. Alternatively you could also remove this last line with `head`, either when generating the data files, or on-the-fly like this:

```
plot '< head -n -1 file.dat' using 4:xtic(6) title 'i386', \
     '' using ($4*1.2) title 'ARMv6',\
     '' using ($4*0.7) title 'AVR'
```

Of course, for your real data you would have something like

```
plot '< head -n -1 file-i386.dat' using 4:xtic(6) title 'i386', \
     '< head -n -1 file-armv6.dat' using ($4*1.2) title 'ARMv6',\
     '< head -n -1 file-avr.dat' using ($4*0.7) title 'AVR'
```

I hope, this gives you an idea of different visualization possiblities. What might be appropriate, you must decide by yourself.